# Use current year as firstDate in showDatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I'm beginning to learn flutter and I'm working with `showDatePicker`
There, I can manually assign the current year to `firstDate`

```
firstDate: DateTime(2021)
```

I'm trying to automatically use the current year as `firstDate`.
For that, what I did so far was:

```
   void _showDatePicker() {
    var currentYear = DateFormat.y().format(DateTime.now()) as DateTime;
    
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: currentYear,
      lastDate: DateTime.now()
      );
     }
```

If I remove `as DateTime` I get the error in `firstDate: currentYear`:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

and if I add `as DateTime`, I get the error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler and more performant solution would be to not use strings at all. They're unnecessary and add additional overhead.

You can get the current year from the [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) object. And pass it to the default `DateTime` constructor. No string conversion, no `intl` package, no performance hit from parsing a date from a string.

```dart
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year),
  lastDate: DateTime.now()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your code this code will work for you.

Your current year is string so i have converted it to int then pass inside DateTime()

```
void _showDatePicker() {
    int currentYear = int.parse(DateFormat.y().format(DateTime.now()));
    showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(currentYear),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please try below code.

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
  lastDate: DateTime(2025),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It actually does not work, as I would be able to choose any date between 2000 and 2025. I want to be able to choose only the dates within the current year (eg: as we are in 2021, I will only be able to choose the dates from 01/01/2021 to the "now" date 03/22/2021)

Answer (score 0):

```
showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
    lastDate: DateTime.now()
);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It actually does not work, as it only gives me the option to choose the "now" date (eg: 03/22/2021) I want to be able to choose any date within the current year